# How to detect dead code on running environment?

Tags: php, code-coverage

A codebase was delivered to me for deploy and maintenance. It happens to be a very messy codebase that grow without code cleaning. So, I suspect that there is about of 80% of dead code there. By dead code here I mean legacy code that is not in use anymore, but is there sitting on the codebase. This number is more a felling than a measurement, the application is simple, there is about 3ain tables and a single flow, I've been tweaking for some months ... Also we have low low low traffic, so no millions of requests per second ...

I want to use something like code coverage to get a heat map of the code, so I can eliminate code that is for sure not in use,  did anyone tried something like that? What are the options?

Comment: by .. erm going through the site? Or doing project-wide searches for function/file names???

Comment: @treyBake There are automated tools for this that make it substantially easier.

Comment: @ceejayoz huh, didn't know.. though I guess that makes this q off-topic for req.-based shenanigans?

Comment: @ceejayoz in fact, they could all be closed as recommendation-based (more about that they will moreorless spawn off-site-answers more than the q's themselves)

Comment: Hey guys thanks! Xdebug is the what I'm looking for!